# nop commerce automapper exception, missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nopcommerce

I have tried to debug and find where the mismatch is coming from but I can not. Any ideas about where to look?

here is the model

```
  public class PatientModel : BaseNopEntityModel
  {
    public PatientModel()
    {
        AvailableStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.FirstName")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.LastName")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.MiddleName")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.RoomNumber")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.HospitalName")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string HospitalName { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.StateProvince")]
    public int? StateProvinceId { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.StateProvince")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.City")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Patient.Fields.ZipPostalCode")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableStates { get; set; }

    public bool FirstNameDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool LastNameDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool MiddleNameDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool RoomNumberDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool HospitalNameDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool StateProvinceDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool CityDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool ZipPostalCodeDisabled { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the entity that it is trying to map to

```
public class Patient : BaseEntity, ICloneable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the first name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the last name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the middle name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the patient room number
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual string HospitalName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the state/province identifier
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int? StateProvinceId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the state/province
    /// </summary>
    public virtual StateProvince StateProvince { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the city
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string City { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the zip/postal code
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string ZipPostalCode { get; set; } 

    public virtual DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }


    public object Clone()
    {
        var pat = new Patient()
        {
            FirstName = this.FirstName,
            LastName = this.LastName,
            MiddleName = this.MiddleName,
            RoomNumber = this.RoomNumber,     
            HospitalName = this.HospitalName,
            StateProvince = this.StateProvince,
            StateProvinceId = this.StateProvinceId,
            City = this.City,
            ZipPostalCode = this.ZipPostalCode,
            CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow 
        };
        return pat;
    }
}
```

and mapper where the issue occurs

```
 public static PatientModel ToModel(this Patient entity)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Patient, PatientModel>(entity);
    }
```

Comment: I found an answer to the issue and had to manually to map the patient entity to the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you never called `Mapper.CreateMap<>()` for those two types.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of getting it to work correctly the only problem was I had to change

```
public static PatientModel ToModel(this Patient entity)
{
    return Mapper.Map<Patient, PatientModel>(entity);
}
```

and remove the mapper and do it manually to map the patient entitiy to the model.